How do I handle map/odom transforms if I want to use robot_localization as well as slam_toolbox?
I'm trying to use slam_toolbox (2d LIDAR) in conjunction with robot_localization (IMU + Wheel Odom). So far my best idea for managing the frames is as shown in the pictures below. However, this results in the map frame in Rviz flickering a lot, and printing the frames shows that odomNew is bypassed. My goal transforms are odom (wheel encoders) <- odomNew (fused with IMU) <- map (slam'd with LIDAR readings). However, I may be approaching this wrong alltogether.
This is my config file for slam_toolbox

This is my config file for robot_localization

Here is my view_frame when I run it:

It basically ignores the odomNew frame alltogether. Is there a better way to do this? Both robot_localization and slam_toolbox work individually, but I can't run both at once properly. Any help is appreciated.

Could we get a screenshot of your frame-tree with rosrun tf view_frames, see here? Just to make sure your frames are actually connected as intended.

@Scoeerg just did. It looks like the odomNew frame isn't being made at all.

I'm starting to think that slam_toolbox doesn't care what you pass into odom_frame or map_frame, and just picks odom and map regardless.

Could we see the launch-file where you are starting the localisation package and pass the parameters?

Turns out I had it right, but in ROS Humble, you need to pass the params file to the slam launch script as slam_param_file, not param_file like in previous vers.

Flickering is must probably caused since there are more than one nodes publishing to the odom (or odomNew) frame.
Generally speaking; there can be more than one odom source but only one node should publish the transformation to odom frame.
In your case both the robot_localization and slam_toolbox publishing the odom transformation, which is causing issues.

Why would slam_toolbox publish a transform to odom? I haven't mentioned the odom frame in its parameters?

On the odom_frame key you gave odomNew as the value. so slam_toolbox will make a transfrom between odom frame and map frame.
It might be my mistake; name of your odom frame is odomNew on your parameters. I was referring to odomNew when i said odom frame
